# AJAX get request em api SPRING BOOT não passa do controller com erro Required request body is missing

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot

Eu estou tentando criar uma APIrest em Springboot para um projeto da faculdade mas sempre que eu faço uma requisição via AJAX na web ele nao passa do controller com o problema Required request body is missing.

Código JS:

```
function login(){
    var matricula = $("#loginAluno").val();
    var senha = $("#senhaAluno").val();

    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/aluno/login",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            data: JSON.stringify({matricula: matricula, senha: senha}),
            contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                window.location.href = "homepage.html";
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(res);
            }
        })
}
```

Codigo Java:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Aluno login(@RequestBody Aluno aluno){
    return alunoRepository.login(aluno.getMatricula(), aluno.getSenha());
}
```

Output:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: public com.api.escola.escola.models.Aluno com.api.escola.escola.controllers.AlunoController.login(com.api.escola.escola.models.Aluno)]
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Como o próprio erro diz, está faltando um corpo na requisição.
Você deveria estar usando o método POST e está usando o GET, a requisição GET não tem um corpo com dados.

Uma alternativa é você trocar o tipo de requisição para POST e no java trocar `@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)` por `@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)`

O método GET só consegue enviar parâmetros pela url (o que deixaria login e senha visíveis) ou em cabeçalhos (incomum para este propósito, ainda que possível).

Recomendo pesquisar sobre métodos HTTP e quando usar GET, POST, etc...

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda, solucionou o problema :)
Contudo eu ainda nao consigo tratar o retorno da chamada, como pode ver, no meu código JS ao retornar um sucesso ele deveria redirecionar para a homepage, entratanto quando há um retorno do servidor ele coloca os parametros na URL e continua na mesma página